# Table 'db.Sessions' doesn't exist

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using `connect-session-sequelize` and trying to overwrite default table to `Session`

```
var SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);

// session setting
app.use(session({
    secret: config.session.secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new SequelizeStore({
        db: sequelize,
        table: 'Session',
        expiration: 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    }),
}));
```

but it's doesn't work: `Table 'db.Sessions' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, I had to add `tableName` property to Session model

```
const Session = sequelize.define('Session', {
        sid: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        expires: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        },
        data: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50000)
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'Session'
    });

    return Session;
```